# How can I make it so that a value becomes "NULL" if there's an Exception?

Tags: python, loops, exception, try-catch

I'm storing data from an API (that I then store as a pickle) and sometimes there are errors due to missing fields. I'm wondering how I can make it so that it only targets the problematic variable and logs its value as "NULL".

The issue is that I'm storing 6 different variables, so if a single one of them has an issue, all other 5 variables will be skipped. Instead, I want that (or those) problematic variables get replaced by the value "NULL" (or None).

meta = loaded_from_pickle('myData.pickle')

```
def getAllData():

    data = []
    for i in range(len(meta)):
        try:
            name = meta[i]['base']['name']
            weight = meta[i]['base']['weight']
            height = meta[i]['base']['height']

            age = meta[i]['secondary']['age']
            eye_color = meta[i]['secondary']['eye_color']
            birthday = meta[i]['secondary']['birthday']

            data.append((name, weight, height, age, eye_color, birthday))

        except:
            pass

    return data

print(getAllData())
```

So what happens is that I end up losing a lot of data points because some data doesn't have "eye_color" or whatnot. So what I should do when there's an "except" should be "make problematic variable = "NULL" ", rather than just passing the entire loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of accessing the keys directly using square brackets try using `get()`  it returns a default value of `None` if the key is not found.

See this answer for more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041421/3125312

You could use it in your code:

```
name = meta[i]['base'].get('name')
weight = meta[i]['base'].get('weight')
height = meta[i]['base'].get('height')
...
```

You could also rewrite your for loop using `enumerate` assuming meta is a list

```
for index, value in enumerate(meta):
    name = value['base'].get('name')
    ...
```

Comment: That works well but what if there's something like meta[i]['base']['fullname']['firstname']?
What if fullname can return None and firstname as well?
['base'].get('fullname').get('firstname') doesn't work because I can't "get" from a None value

Comment: `get()` takes in a second argument to use as a default value instead of `None` - use a dict as a default for fullname - `['base'].get('fullname', {}).get('firstname')`